# How to start an Activity from non Activity view in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I need to create new intent and start it from an adapter for a recyclerView kotlin class.

I've tried to `addOnClickListener` on the item needed. then creating intent and start it.

Here is the code:

```
        mDressImage1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dressImage_1)
        mDressImage1!!.setOnClickListener {
                            val detailsActivity = Intent(context, DressDetailsActivity::class.java)
                        context!!.startActivity(detailsActivity)
                    }
```

Expected to work normally but return me this error message : 
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`

and it crashes every time I click the view.

Comment: Use interface or Lamda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main Cause is Your 'context' is null.
try using context from 'itemView' like following

```
mDressImage1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dressImage_1)
        mDressImage1!!.setOnClickListener {
                            val detailsActivity = Intent(itemView.getContext(), DressDetailsActivity::class.java)
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(detailsActivity)
                    }
```

Vote if it works.

Thanks.

Happy Coding.